# List comprehension break statement

Tags: python

How can I stop the iteration of list comprehension when a particular element is found
For example:

```
list1=[a for a in list2 if a==someelement]
```

As soon as "a equals someelement",list1 should be set to a and no further iterations should be executed.

Comment: You can't directly. There are ways to achieve that result using `itertools`, but a plain `for` loop is probably easier. Assuming your situation is actually complex enough that direct assignment as Volatility describes below doesn't work. If you really want to use a list comprehension, `dropwhile` is the place to start: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile

Comment: In other words, you want `list1 = [someelement]`?

Comment: @Volatility: Yes,I expect list1=[someelement]

Answer (score 4):

Based on Volatility's solution:

```
list1 = [someelement] if someelement in list2 else []
```

Comment: While this is not a list comprehension, I think this is the best/cleanest way to solve the particular problem.

Comment: Depends on aliasing. `[someelement]` will be equal to `[a]` (where `a` is the first matching element found in `list2`), but depending what you do with it and the types involved it may not have equivalent behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [takewhile](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x<42, [2, 3, 4, 42, 5, 6, 7])))
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand you were looking to do this within a list comprehension, but it cannot be done.

Consider this solution.  You can probably tighten this up, but I trust the code is easily understood.

```
list1 = []
for a in list2: 
  list1.append(a)
  if a == some_element: break
```

Comment: Close, but to meet the stated design (nonsensical as it is) you shouldn't `append` unless `a == some_element`. This is such an exercise in attempted mind-reading that I don't know whether or not you're on the right track.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, I understand many are interpreting the question that way, but I decided to interpret it differently.  Since the literal question is, as you say, nonsense... I assumed @s02 was actually asking to *stop* the iterative generation of the list after appending `some_element`. Mind-reading, agreed.  :-)

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: I just could not understand the reason a particular question is being tagged as "nonsensical",I thought this forum is for sharing ideas/knowledge and not being judgemental about other's questions who are newbies.Although agreed,I should have been more clear with my question,which I think is easier to demand instead of making nonsensical/baseless comments...

Answer (score 2):

If your 'someelement' has a fixed value, than you do not need a list comprehension even. All you have to do is :

```
list1 = list2[:list2.index(someelement)]
```

And your job is done :)

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using list comprehension with `break`, you can achieve your goal by this hackish way:

(I find your question is kind of ambiguous, return all the elements util met `someelement`, or just return first `someelement`. So I write two versions.)

```
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5]
someelment = 3

list1 = [a for end in [[]] for a in list2
         if not end and not (a == someelment and end.append(42))]

# output: [1, 2, 3]

list1 = [a for end in [[]] for a in list2
         if not end and a == someelment and not end.append(42)]

# output: [3]
```

Explanation for tricks:

1. The key point is building an `end` condition in list comprehension, exclude rest element when `end` is not empty. (actually not break out, but indeed in logic)
2. use `for end in [[]]` to initialize a variable in list comprehension.
3. use lazy explanation in `and/or` to divide branch logics.

Notice, it is just a study and exploit of list comprehension, may gives you some inspirations, and should not be used in production code.